# Can I retroactively add a foreign key ID column and populate it with the values of another table's primary key without having to enter manually?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables:

```
Table1 (TagID, TagName, Primary Key (TagID)<br>
Table2 (TagName,ProductName, ProductID)
```

I would like to add a `TagID` column to `Table2` and populate it with `TagIDs` from `table1` where `TagName=TagName`.

Is this possible without going through and individually entering the TagIDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by altering the table and then updating the values:

```
alter table table2 add column TagId int;

update table2 t2 join
       table1 t1
       on t2.TagName = t1.TagName
    set t2.TagId = t1.TagId;

alter table table2 add constraint fk_table2_tagid
    foreign key (TagId) references table1(TagId);
```

I would recommend building an index on `table1(TagName)` for performance.

Comment: I would update the values before adding the FK constraint. After doing the update, you still may find some records that are orphaned since you didn't have an FK originally. They may need manual resolution.

Comment: I had to update the values before adding the foreign key constraint as it wouldn't let me do it the other way round. Makes sense as none of the IDs in the parent table were null and this obviously caused an issue when I tried to set the relationship.

Guys, thank you so much for your help!